# Why does using enhanced for-loop for implementing bubble sort is giving me ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException?

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, for-loop

We all know that coding for-loop is taking too long to type. That's why I tried converting my long for-loop to enhanced for-loop but everytime I compile my code I'm having`IndexOutOfBoundException`.

With a sample array:

> int[] array = {5, 4, 3, 2, 1};

**Simple Loop Version (Working Code)**

```
public static int[] bubbleSort(int[] array) {
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 1; j < array.length - i; j++) {
            if (array[j - 1] > array[j]) {
                int temp = array[j - 1];
                array[j - 1] = array[i];
                array[i] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Enhanced for-loop (Not Working)**

```
 public static int[] bubbleSort(int[] array) {
    for (int i : array) {
        for (int j : array) {
            if (array[j - 1] > array[j]) {
                int temp = array[j - 1];
                array[j - 1] = array[i];
                array[i] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It's giving me:

> Error: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 5

Comment: Fencepost error at the lower bound: 0 instead of 1, so j-1 is -1, which is not of course workable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You misunderstand of the enhanced `for` loop. The values you get are the **entries** in the array, not their indexes.

This may help clarify:

```
int[] foo = {10, 20, 30};
for (int n : foo) {
    System.out.println(n);
}
```

...will show

```
10
20
30
```

**not**

```
0
1
2
```

[Live Example](http://ideone.com/v9nuUo)

The enhanced `for` loop wouldn't be appropriate for a bubble sort.

Answer (score 2):

In the enumerate syntax:

```
for(int i : numbers) {
    ....
}
```

`i` is the *value*, not the index. So if you have a value in your array that is greater than the length of the array you will get an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`